# "I am one of them who likes fast food"

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, sentence-structure, american-english, british-english

Usually we say "I am one of those who likes fast food" but If i replace "those" with "them", could i also "I am one of them who likes fast food"?

Answer (score 3):

The use of "them" here is wrong when used this way in modern English to refer to people who like fast food. The word was used in this way for the 1662 version of the Lord's Prayer: *And forgive us our trespasses, As we forgive them that trespass against us*, but more recent versions use "those".

You might however have been discussing how chefs dislike fast food, and if you are yourself a chef who happens to like fast food you might correctly say "I am one of them, who likes fast food".

Comment: If i am discussing a point and that point goes parallel with my liking then i should say " i am one of them" but how about if i say " I am not of those"?

Comment: "I am one of them" means I am a member of the group being discussed, and has nothing to do with what I like unless that is what characterises the group. "I am not of those" is also unusual; most people would say "I am not *one* of those".

Comment: Cheers, last thing, Could i also say "I am one of those" referring to the group being discussed?

Comment: "I am one of them" would be better. "Those" often needs a plural noun following, e.g. those people, those chefs (the chefs that are being discussed).

Answer (score 1):

*Usually* we don't use this kind of construction at all. Usually one would say "I like fast food", or perhaps "I'm a person who likes fast food".

The construction with "one of those" is from fairly formal speech.  Simply replacing by "them" doesn't work well.  But you can say, for example "Some people (I am one of them) who like fast food are going to Macdonalds"

Comment: When I was growing up in London, in the 1950s and 1960s, _one of them_ had a particular meaning, so that one avoided the phrase for two reasons.

Comment: I assume it is this sense:
 https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Concise_New_Partridge_Dictionary_of/Ak6cBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22one+of+them%22+slang&pg=RA11-PA2000&printsec=frontcover  However that lists "one of those" as a synonym.

Comment: Yes, that sense, although, as I grew up in Lambeth ('Lambeff') I tended to hear the more demotic version. My own parents, however, were at pains to get me to 'talk proper'.